# Finding value of an exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $ x^2=3x-1$ then find the value of $(x^6+1)/x^3$ I used the quadratic but it became too complicated

Comment: No that question was different

Comment: This is not an exponential equation.  That would be an equation where the variable, rather than constants, is in the exponent.

Comment: The are the same questions; both are homework dumps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x\neq 0$, so

$$x^2=3x-1\stackrel{:x}\iff x+\frac{1}{x}=3$$

$$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3=27\tag{1}$$

$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+3x\frac{1}{x}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+9\tag{2}$$

$$(1)(2)\implies x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=18$$